# How to prevent deselect of last option in TableView with AllowsMultipleSelection = True?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a TableView with AllowsMultipleSelection = True, allowing the user to select as many rows as they like. I would like my TableView to have at least one option selected so that the user not selecting anything would not be an option.

How do I implement validation such that when the user tries to unselect the last selected option in the TableView it would still stay selected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your class is set as the delegate for the UITableView and then put this in:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
    if let selectedIndices = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {
        return selectedIndices.count > 1 ? indexPath : nil
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

What that does is to prevent deselection of a cell if there are no selected cells (shouldn't happen really) or there is only 1 selected cell.

It could probably be condensed to just this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
    return tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows!.count > 1 ? indexPath : nil
}
```

as I don't see how you can be deselecting if you have no selected indicies but I don't like to force unwrap things just in case.